# Redirect loop webpage (deployed using tomcat)

Tags: java, spring, maven, tomcat7, myfaces

Recently i am making a project using maven, jsf (myfaces), hibernate, and spring technology. Before deploy it using tomcat, i running it through jetty plugin. It seems ok until i deploy its war package to my tomcat webapps (7.0.41). There is no problem when deploying, but when i start to browse my project (localhost:8080/myproject) it says `this webpage has a redirect loop`.

here i capture some information,

web.xml

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>/index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

part of pom.xml

```
 <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.cargo</groupId>
            <artifactId>cargo-maven2-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.3.1</version>
             <configuration>
              <wait>false</wait>
              <container>
                 <containerId>tomcat5x</containerId>
                 <type>remote</type>
              </container>
              <configuration>
                 <type>runtime</type>
                 <properties>
                     <cargo.tomcat.manager.url>http://localhost:${tomcat.server.port}/manager</cargo.tomcat.manager.url>
                     <cargo.remote.username>tomcat</cargo.remote.username>
                     <cargo.remote.password>tomcat</cargo.remote.password>
                     <cargo.servlet.port>${tomcat.server.port}</cargo.servlet.port>
                 </properties>
              </configuration>
              <deployer>
                <type>remote</type>
                <deployables>
                  <deployable>
                    <groupId>${pom.groupId}</groupId>
                    <artifactId>lips-crew-web</artifactId>
                    <type>war</type>
                    <pingURL>http://localhost:${tomcat.server.port}/lica/index.jsp</pingURL>
                    <properties>
                       <context>lica</context>
                    </properties>
                  </deployable>     
                </deployables>
              </deployer>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

which `${tomcat.server.port}` = 8080'

**EDIT**

index.jsp

```
    <%@ page language="java" errorPage="/error.jsp" pageEncoding="UTF-8" contentType="text/html;charset=utf-8" %>
    <%@ taglib uri="http://acegisecurity.org/authz" prefix="authz" %>
    <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
    <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" prefix="fmt" %>
    <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/sql" prefix="sql" %>
    <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" prefix="h" %>
    <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" prefix="f" %>
    <%@ taglib uri="http://corejsf.com/validator" prefix="v" %>
    <%@ taglib uri="http://myfaces.apache.org/tomahawk" prefix="t" %>
    <%@ taglib uri="http://www.opensymphony.com/sitemesh/decorator" prefix="decorator" %>
    <%@ taglib uri="http://www.opensymphony.com/sitemesh/page" prefix="page" %>
    <c:redirect url="/mainMenu.html"/>
```

I dont know what other info you need but just tell me if you want. 
Really appreciate your help guys. Thanks.

Comment: Provide some info about index.jsp. Also create a new page `test.jsp` and try to open it in your browser. And I would remove the slash in your `<welcome-file>` element, it can be the cause of your problem.

Comment: edited and i have been remove that slash actually.

Comment: What about removing `<c:redirect url="/mainMenu.html"/>`? Why do you need to redirect from welcome JSP page to HTML page?

Comment: are you using spring security? IF so can you post the security spring config

Comment: @klimpond i've try to remove `redirect` url, there is no change, and it just part to redirect too main menu when you just logged in,
@jhadesdev ya, i use spring security. But it's too much when i post it here, which part i should be check?

Comment: According to your "redirect loop" message there has to be two pages one redirecting to another and back again. Try building brand new JSP page saying just "Hello word". Tell me if it works.